# inaccessible properties of objects

Tags: c#, properties, textblock

I am using C#, Silverlight.

Some properties of some objects don't seem to be available to me. For example, the TextBlock class is supposed to have a Background property, but my Visual Studio doesn't seem to realize it.

My example code:

```
// myTextBlock is a TextBlock, myColor is a SolidColorBrush.Color
// these objects were both initiated elsewhere
myTextBlock.Foreground= myColor;
```

The Foreground property works just fine.

But if I try the Background property:

```
myTextBlock.Background = myColor;
```

This doesn't work as Visual Studio doesn't recognize that TextBlocks have a Background property.

Online documentation of the TextBlock class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: It doesn't show up in Intellisense. Turns out Silverlight version of TextBlock doesn't have the same properties as other versions of TextBlock. Dennis's answer below solved the mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextBlock.Background` isn't available in Silverlight.

There's framework version switch at the top of MSDN pages. Turn it into 'Silverlight' position, an you'll see actual properties list.

Comment: Ahhh that totally solves it. It seems so obvious now but I never would have figured that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`TextBlock` doesn't have a `Background` property in Silverlight. It actually doesn't have a proper background. Think of it as a transparent container for text.

You can work around this with a `Border`:

```
<Border Background="[your color]" BorderBrush="Transparent"> 
    <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

Beware though: you're going to move all positioning/sizing properties (`Grid.Row`, `Margin` ...) from the `TextBlock` to the `Border` itself to keep it where it is.

Comment: Thanks! I actually only need to highlight the TextBlock in some way, and since Background doesn't exist, I've been doing it with the Foreground property. But I was still curious as to why the Intellisense didn't find the property, and turns out it's because of Silverlight :P